# Defining the length of sequence instead of the step size

Tags: python, list, range, sequence

I am new to python and want a function which produces a list that contains a number of integers i.e. [1,3,5,7....] like you can do with the range function i.e. range(1,21,2).

However instead of setting the upper limit I want to set how long the list should be, so I would state the starting point, the step and the number of integers I want in my list.  Does such a function exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but it's pretty easy to make one:

```
def myrange(start, step, count):
    return range(start, start + (step * count), step)
```

short demonstration:

```
>>> myrange(10, 2, 5)
[10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
>>> myrange(10, -2, 5)
[10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
```

In python 3 it'll return a `range` object, just like the regular `range()` function would:

```
>>> myrange(10, 2, 5)
range(10, 20, 2)
>>> list(myrange(10, 2, 5))
[10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Answer (score 5):

Martijn Pieter's answer is good for integers. If `start` or`step` may be floats, you could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[start+i*step for i in range(count)]
```

Comment: +1. But maybe a generator would be nicer: `(start+i*step for i in range(count))`, as range is also a generator (at least in 3).

Comment: @Hyperboreus: I think "nicer" depends on the situation. If you have enough memory, a list comprehension may be faster (assuming you need to use the whole list). But if you are tight on memory, then a generator is better.